# Why is there a comma in the React import statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When creating a React app there's the common:

`import React, {Component} from 'react';`

import statement.  I'm curious why the line requires a comma?  I've tried looking this up and cannot find an explanation.

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import, but basically it's JavaScript syntax for the `import` statement. `export` is similar.

Comment: Please don't downvote this, as it is a good question

Comment: If you look at this [line](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fe959eea731b4de0c970f753dfa9d0f6b010b63d/packages/react/src/React.js#L37), will see the file exports just a *default export React*. Now React is exporting a object which contains `Component`, `Fragement` etc.. There you don't have any named exports for  `Component`, `Fragement` etc... But `import React, {Component} from 'react';` syntax seems like the `react` file has it...

Comment: ..It is basically **babel** doing all this thing. babel is taking the properties off of `React` and making them be fake named exports, [link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4996#issuecomment-267024616). This is not even _ecmascript compliant_.

Comment: ..I got to know about this from [IRC](https://botbot.me/freenode/reactjs/2018-08-20/?msg=103534241&page=6) when I raised it there. If you are interested, please read the discussion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `React` is the **default export** from `'react'`.

After the comma comes a list of **other exports** from `'react'`.

As mentioned in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the syntax for an import statement can look like this:

`import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";`

Comment: So if the comma is included that is a way to say "I only want this one item...Component"?  and if I use import React from 'react'; I'm importing the whole module?

Comment: @szaske No. The comma separates two items, so it's a way to say "I want these two items, the default export (`React`) and one specific item from it (`React.Component`)."

Comment: Thanks JJJ that makes sense and is the best explanation I've heard so far.

Answer (score 3):

**Foo.js**

```
export const bar = "bar";
export default "baz";
```

or:

```
export const bar = "bar";
const baz = "baz";
export default baz;
```

`bar` is a named export and must be imported with `{}`.
`baz` is the default export and can be imported with **any** name without `{}`.

```
import baz, { bar } from "Foo";
console.log( baz, bar );
```

or

```
import bazButIwantFizz, { bar } from "Foo";
console.log( bazButIwantFizz, bar );
```

or

```
import bazButIwantFizz, { bar as barButIWantBuzz };
console.log( bazButIwantFizz, barButIWantBuzz );
```

So, we can import named and default exports separating with a comma.
As suggested in the comments, refer to the [related documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Answer (score 0):

You must be using JSX (html syntax) in the file, which requires `React` as an import dependency, exported as default from 'react' module.

Then you import `Component` as a named import, denoted in JS within {}. There are other things like {Fragment, createElement} that you can do if required.

Refer [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/%E2%80%A6) for more.

Comment: You can do named imports, only for named exports. But in react the file exporting `React` has no named exports except the `default export React`. It works right now, but it is something that was being made for use forcibly with some unknown _magic_.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the correction. They do export the object as such, like named import. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/React.js#L37

Answer (score -2):

As @Derek said in the comment above. This is one possible syntax  for import.

[link shamelessly stolen from @Derek](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)